# Start and Stop timer not working

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am trying to make a timer that starts when you click the top button and stops and resets when you click the bottom button.  Here is a link to my fiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/AbrGL/

My HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id="start-clock" value="Click here to start timer" name="submit" onClick="startclock()"/>
<div id="timer">0</div>
<input type="submit" id="stop-clock" value="Click here to stop and reset the timer" name="submit" onClick="stopclock()"/>
```

My JavaScript:

```
function startClock() {
    if (clicked === false) {
        clock = setInterval("stopWatch()", 1000);
        clicked = true;
    }
    else if (clicked === true) {
    }
}
function stopWatch() {
    sec+;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec;
}
function stopClock() {
    window.clearInterval(clock);
    sec = 0;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=0;
    clicked = false;
}
```

Comment: So many typos in your fiddle

Comment: Fixing your typos, it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/VDVFU/ (fiddle needs to be set to execute as `No wrap - in <head>` so the JS is global and the HTML buttons can access the functions, HTML buttons called wrong functions - things are case-sensitive in JS, `sec+` needed to be `sec++`, and variables should/need to be defined).

Comment: first thing I noted, it should be `sec++;` and not `sec+;` in the `stopWatch` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok you have a lot of typos.

First, `sec+;` does not do anything. It should be `sec++;`.

Second, your `onClick` properties point to `startclock()` and `stopclock()`, which should actually be `startClock()` and `stopClock()`. Function names are case-sensitive in JavaScript.

Third, the `clicked` variable is undefined so `startClock()` will never actually do anything. Add `var clicked = false;` before your function declarations.

Last but not least, `sec` is undefined, so incrementing it doesn't make sense. Add `var sec = 0;` before your function declarations.

HTML should look like

```
<input type="submit" id="start-clock" value="Click here to start timer" name="submit" onClick="startClock()"/>

<div id="timer">0</div>

<input type="submit" id="stop-clock" value="Click here to stop and reset the timer" name="submit" onClick="stopClock()"/>
```

and JavaScript should look like

```
var clicked = false;
var sec = 0;

function startClock() {
    if (clicked === false) {
        clock = setInterval("stopWatch()", 1000);
        clicked = true;
    }
    else if (clicked === true) {
    }
}

function stopWatch() {
    sec++;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec;
}

function stopClock() {
    window.clearInterval(clock);
    sec = 0;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=0;
    clicked = false;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle with the changes above: http://jsfiddle.net/AbrGL/8/

Comment: You didn't mention that you changed the fiddle to run as `No wrap - in <head>`. If you don't do that, your changes won't matter

Answer (score 3):

In the "stopWatch()" method, Replace `sec+;` with `sec++;`

I also found some typos, JavaScript is a CaSe SeNsitIvE language

Answer (score 2):

I've made a few changes dom and js

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="start-clock" value="Click here to start timer"/>
<div id="timer">0</div>
<input type="button" id="stop-clock" value="Click here to stop and reset the timer"/>
```

JS

```
var clock;
var sec = 0;
document.getElementById("start-clock").addEventListener("click",function(){
 clock = setInterval(stopWatch,1000);
},false);
function stopWatch() {
    sec++;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec;
}

document.getElementById("stop-clock").addEventListener("click",function(){
 window.clearInterval(clock);
  sec = 0;
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=sec;
},false);
```

and have a look at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbrGL/6/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

http://tutorialzine.com/2015/04/material-design-stopwatch-alarm-and-timer/

this is the best i have ever used, you can make little changes accordingly if required.

Comment: Please add your answer here, links can become unavailable in time.