# How to remove or disable evenListeners on click

Tags: javascript, html

I got to evenListeners one to start the timer and one to stop it
Is it possible to make the start one to work only once and then get disabled until the stop button is clicked ???

```
startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", function stopFunction() {})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a setInterval function on click, and restart after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179841/how-to-stop-a-setinterval-function-on-click-and-restart-after-a-few-seconds)

Comment: also: [Why won't my countdown timer start and stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638402/why-wont-my-countdown-timer-start-and-stop) and [Start and Stop timer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237502/start-and-stop-timer-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `removeEventListener`

```js
function startTimer() {
  // whatever code

  // Disable after use
  startButton.removeEventListern("click", startTimer);
}
startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);

// Reset listener after stop button clicked
stopButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  startButton.removeEventListener("click", startTimer);
  startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);
});
```

---

Can also simplify with shorthand:

```js
const disableBtn = () => startButton.removeEventListener("click", startTimer);
const enableBtn = () => (disableBtn(), startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer));

function startTimer() {
  // whatever code
  disableBtn();
}
enableBtn();
stopButton.addEventListner("click", enableBtn);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what to what is to use boolean (I called it `timerOn`) like in the following:

```js
let timerOn = false;

function startTimer() {
  if (timerOn) {
    return;
  }
  timerOn = true;
  // do what you need below
}
startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);

stopButton.addEventListener("click", function stopFunction() {
  if (!timerOn) return;

  startButton.removeEventListern("click", startTimer);
  timerOn = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

by using the line below you can remove the listener.

```
 startbutton.removeEventListener("click", startTimer);
```

and if you want to handle it with another button just call a function on click.

```
function stopFunction() {
   startbutton.removeEventListener("click", startTimer);
});
```